# How to test that a function returns an object using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Assume this is my function I am trying to test:

```
self.fetch = {
 things: function() {
   return $http.get("/api/things/")
     .then(function(response) {
         return response.data;
   });
 }
};
```

And this is my current test:

```
it('fetch.thingss() should GET to /api/things/ and return object', function() {
    mockBackend.expectGET("/api/things/").respond(204, {data: {th: 'th'}});

    var p = BaseService.fetch.things();


    p.then(function(response){
        expect(response.data).toEqual({th: 'th'});
       });

    mockBackend.flush();
});
```

But this currently just tests that `response.data` is what it should be. How do I test the the function returns `response.data`?

Comment: You mean like, test that it returns `response.data` and not `response.foo`?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Yup, exactly that.

Comment: I don't think that is feasible. You'd have to test that the object returned is not ... every possible object _except_ `response.data`

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I just want to check that it returns `data: {th: 'th'}` (the item being returned from `GET`). This isn't feasible? (considering I have the return statement `return response.data;`?

Comment: Isn't that what your test is already doing?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari From my understanding, `expect(response.data).toEqual({th: 'th'});` is testing that the item being passed To the `then` is `{data: {th: 'th'}` (it is not checking that the item being Returned is `{data: {th: 'th'}`.

Comment: You mean something like `expect(response).toEqual({data: {th: 'th'}})`?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Nope, `response` and `response.data` are just the objects being passed into `then`. I want to test that `then` actually Returns that object.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do, but have a look at `expect()..to.have.property()`: http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_property